# simulate key and trackpad events nightwatch

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mousewheel, nightwatch.js, trackpad

I need to simulate scrolling using mouse wheel and trackpad. Is there any way in which I can do this in nightwatch or javascript?The nightwatch documentation does not have anything mentioned for mousewheel and trackpad.Any guidance in this issue would be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

use `window.scrollBy(x,y)`

Change x for horizontal and y for vertical scroll increments